# How can I show cookies in to codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, cookies

how can I show cookies?

i want see cookies in codeigniter.

session i see :

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

But cookies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at `system/core/Input.php`:

```
function _fetch_from_array(&$array, $index = '', $xss_clean = FALSE)
{
    if ( ! isset($array[$index]))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ($xss_clean === TRUE)
    {
        return $this->security->xss_clean($array[$index]);
    }

    return $array[$index];
}

function cookie($index = '', $xss_clean = FALSE)
{
    return $this->_fetch_from_array($_COOKIE, $index, $xss_clean);
}
```

As far as I can see, you cannot show all cookies with `$this->input->cookie()`. Only one at a time.

If you really want to see all the cookies, just try `var_dump($_COOKIE)`.

Or if you need show one cookie only, specify `your_key`: `$this->input->cookie('your_key')`

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$this->input->cookie()`.

For more options use the cookie helper: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Comment: I do not understand how to view cookies print_r ($ this-> input-> cookie ()); Give please example?

Comment: Yes. If you know the cookie name use it like this: `print_r ($ this-> input-> cookie ('COOKIE_NAME'));`